# Deleting specific article from database with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm creating a blog site and I got stuck in this phase where I want to allow authors to delete their own posts, they can already see the delete button below each of their posts. In the DB table I have an author, content and ID of the article. Now I need to get the specific ID of the article that they want to delete, but I have no idea how to do this, the delete button is the same for every article, so I can't use that for help. I have this code to get articles from my DB and the button click code ready. For better imagination here is an image of the site -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szldx.png]

```
 ... previous code
 <?php } 

    $articles->ArticlesConn();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles_table");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    // loop to generate content
    ?>  
    <div class="container"> // responsive stuff
     <div class="row">      // responsive stuff
      <div class="twelve columns">  // responsive stuff
    <?php
    echo       "<h3>" . $row['Title'] . "</h3>
                <p>" . $row['Content'] . "</p>"; ?>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="eight columns">
                <address><?php echo "Author - " . $row['Author']; ?> </address><br><br><br> /// nick of the author below each article
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">

                <?php
                if ($row['Author'] == $_SESSION["username"]) // show delete button if the logged user is an author of generated article
                { ?>
                    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete article"/>         
          <?php }   ?>
      </div>    
      </div>
     </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Get all blog posts of author from DB table and put all posts with buttons in the loop of posts of author which you fetch from DB. Assign post id as 'id ' to each button.

Comment: you need to use isset for delete also.for example if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 $query =  "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE username=$username";

Comment: Oh yeah, so how do I assign the ID to the button? I don't know any way how to transfer variable from php to html - i need something like this  <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete article" id="<?php $row['ID'] ?>"/>   can that work?

Comment: yeah, something like <button id="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?> works

Comment: Ok great, now comes the last thing, ID to the button is set in html mark, now I need to get it back in php - if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {   } . Anyone knows how do I get the ID back?

Comment: You could make an AJAX request to the new script that accepts the article ID, checks the credentials and on OK, deletes the article.
The response of this AJAX request ('You do not have sufficient credentials for this action.' or 'The article was successfully deleted.') could be than displayed on the page where the user clicked the "Delete" button.

Comment: Well I have no idea how to write AJAX requests, but I think I'm pretty close to solving my problem, just need to know which button was clicked - each button now has unique ID that equals to the ID of article, but at the same time all buttons have same name="delete" and putting code in to brackets if (isset($_POST['delete'])) { } will completely ignore the ID, that's where I'm stuck right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you should add a form to wrap your input.

This form will call the page itself. In this form there is a hidden input with the value of the article id. So when you submit the form, you can get the article id via $_POST['name of the hidden input'].

I will show you the code :

```
<?php } 

   if (isset($_POST['article-id'])) {
       // prevent SQL injection
       $articleId = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['article-id']);
       $res = mysql_query('DELETE FROM articles_tab WHERE id='.$articleId);

       if (!$res) {
          die(mysql_error());
       }
   }

   $articles->ArticlesConn();
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles_table");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    // loop to generate content
   ?>  
   <div class="container"> // responsive stuff
    <div class="row">      // responsive stuff
     <div class="twelve columns">  // responsive stuff
   <?php
   echo       "<h3>" . $row['Title'] . "</h3>
               <p>" . $row['Content'] . "</p>"; ?>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="eight columns">
                <address><?php echo "Author - " . $row['Author']; ?> </address><br><br><br> /// nick of the author below each article
     </div>
     <div class="four columns">

               <?php
               if ($row['Author'] == $_SESSION["username"]) // show delete button if the logged user is an author of generated article
               { ?>
           <form method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="article-id" value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"/>
               <input type="submit" value="Delete article"/>    
           </form>     
         <?php } ?>
     </div>    
     </div>
    </div>
   <?php
       }
```

But you should use mysqli or PDO instead of the old mysql extension, look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: yeah, I didn't search how to prevent SQL injection with this old extension.
Just escape the $_POST['article-id'] like this Readerik : 
$articleId = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['article-id']);
I edited the original answer